# Theme setting to change block position (region)

Tags: 8

i want to create a theme setting to change blocks position(region) for ex.

> option_1 block_branding-> region_top block_main_menu-> region_menu
>
> option_2 block_branding-> region_branding block_main_menu->
>   region_header_first

I think that should do something like:

- Create a file with a function to change the region of the blocks according to option.
- Call this function when the form is submitted.

But I don't how to get block info to change its position.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should change each desired block region for your theme manually at `Administration>Structure>Block layout Tab` and then go to the config export function at:
  `Administration>Configuration>Development>Configuration synchronization>Export Tab>Full archive` to export all the block settings for your theme.
Then you should take a look at to the generated YAML files and placed them in a new folder within your theme at `/config/install`. you then uninstalled the theme and then reinstalled it as the default.